# Better way to merge pdfs

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge two pdfs - one from a razor view and one from a file on the server.  To create the pdf from the razor view I have used the following nuget package: [MVCRazorToPDF](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf).

Unfortunately this didn't allow me to merge an existing file with the pdf so I have downloaded the project and changed the `PdfActionResult` to accept a mergeFilename.

I then generate the new pdf using the following:

```
public byte[] GeneratePdfOutput(ControllerContext context, object model = null, string viewName = null,
    Action<PdfWriter, Document> configureSettings = null, string filename = null)
{
    byte[] output;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && File.Exists(filename))
    {
        using (var copyDoc = new Document())
        {
            using (var copyStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                copyDoc.Open();

                PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(copyDoc, copyStream);
                copy.CloseStream = false;
                copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(GetBytes(context, model, viewName, configureSettings)));

                using (var reader = new PdfReader(filename))
                {
                    reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        PdfImportedPage page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                        copy.AddPage(page);
                    }
                }

                copy.Close();
                copyDoc.Close();
                output = copyStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output = GetBytes(context, model, viewName, configureSettings);
    }

    return output;
}

private byte[] GetBytes(ControllerContext context, object model = null, string viewName = null, Action<PdfWriter, Document> configureSettings = null)
{
    if (viewName == null)
    {
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    }

    context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            if (configureSettings != null)
            {
                configureSettings(writer, document);
            }

            document.Open();

            using (var reader = new StringReader(RenderRazorView(context, viewName)))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader);
                document.Close();
                return workStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was anyway to do this so that the `GetBytes` was part of the first function - ie I open a new document and then add the razor and if there is a file on the server, I add that using the same memory stream and document (rather than having to create new ones), without the need for the else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the first line from

> ```
> byte[] output;
> ```

to

```
byte[] output = GetBytes(context, model, viewName, configureSettings);
```

and then revert the `if` condition you can return early.

So the remaining code (if the filename is valid and the file exists) could become

- by stacking the usings which saves some horizontal spacing
- by using the `byte[] output` for the `PdfReader` ctor
- and using `copyStream.GetBuffer()` instead of calling its `ToArray()` method which eleminates the creation of an additional array

like so

```
public byte[] GeneratePdfOutput(ControllerContext context, object model = null, string viewName = null,
    Action<PdfWriter, Document> configureSettings = null, string filename = null)
{
    byte[] output = GetBytes(context, model, viewName, configureSettings);  

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) || !File.Exists(filename))
    {
        return output;
    }

    using (var copyDoc = new Document())
    using (var copyStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        copyDoc.Open();

        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(copyDoc, copyStream);
        copy.CloseStream = false;
        copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(output));

        using (var reader = new PdfReader(filename))
        {
            reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                copy.AddPage(page);
            }
        }

        copy.Close();
        copyDoc.Close();
        return copyStream.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to get rid of GetBytes function altogether?

Comment: Ahh, it's based on iTextSharp.  If no one is able to come up with a better answer then I'll accept this one.  Thanks for the improvements

Comment: Just few notes: no need to call `copy.Close()` and `copyDoc.Close()` (they're already on using), same for `document.Close()` in `GetBytes()`). Also no need to set  `writer.CloseStream` (it's safe to "dispose" `MemoryStream` twice). Well I'd also pick a better name for `GetBytes()`...

Comment: They should be iTextSharp classes, they're (AFAIK).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti if I don't call the closes, the `copyStream` isn't set

Comment: @Pete `copyStream` is just a `MemoryStream` (a `Stream` implementation around a byte array), it may be empty because `pdfCopy` didn't flush but if you proper wrap `pdfCopy` inside its own `using` (with inner scope than `copyStream`) then it'll flush when disposed (with the side effect to be effectively closed also in case of exceptions, now it's not)